# How to train features in different scales in deep learning model

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm new in deep learning and I built a very simple model to try to train my data. I have two features input: `sex` and `age`. `sex` is `0` or `1` and `age` is between `25` and `60`. Output is just `0` means this person has no such disease and `1` means has such disease.

However, when I train my model, the training loss does not decrease at all. It looks like because my two features are very different in range. So how can I fix this? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

My code is here:

```py
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net,self).__init__()

        self.fc1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(2,50),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(50,2)
        )

    def forward(self,x):
        x = self.fc1(x)

        x = F.softmax(x, dim=1)
        return x

#Inputs
X = np.column_stack((sex,age))
X = torch.from_numpy(X).type(torch.FloatTensor)
y = torch.from_numpy(y).type(torch.LongTensor)


#Initialize the model        
model = Net()
#Define loss criterion
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
#Define the optimizer
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)

epochs = 1000

losses = []
for i in range(epochs):

    y_pred = model.forward(X)
    #Compute Cross entropy loss
    loss = criterion(y_pred,y)
    #Add loss to the list
    losses.append(loss.item())
    #Clear the previous gradients
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    #Compute gradients
    loss.backward()
    #Adjust weights
    optimizer.step()
    _, predicted = torch.max(y_pred.data, 1)

    if i % 50 == 0:
        print(loss.item())
```

And the train loss looks like this

```
0.9273738861083984
0.6992899179458618
0.6992899179458618
0.6992899179458618
0.6992899179458618
0.6992899179458618
0.6992899179458618
0.6992899179458618
0.6992899179458618
0.6992899179458618
0.6992899179458618
0.6992899179458618
0.6992899179458618
0.6992899179458618
```

**EDIT**

Thank you for your comments. Sorry I didn't explain my question clearly. This is part of my network and my input data contains two parts: the first part is some signal data and I use CNN model to train it and it works well; the second part is what I mentioned above. My goal is to merge two models to improve my accuracy.
I've tried normalization and looks like it works. I want to know is it always necessary to do normalization when pre-processing data? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried simple normalization? Like Z-score or min-max should simply work in this case.

Comment: Regardless of scaling, are you certain that only those two inputs can predict your output with better loss than that?

Comment: And finally, are you sure neural network is necessary? It's not like it's gonna learn anything sensible and will overfit badly to your data. BTW. You should have `1` output, not `2` as it's binary. And you shouldn't use activation at the end of the network and use `torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss` or use `sigmoid` at the end and `torch.nn.NLLLoss` (negative log-likelihood).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**An alternative.**

If the age has discrete values in the range `(25-60)`, then one possible way would be to learn embeddings for those two attributes, `sex` and `age`.

For example,

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()

        self.sex_embed = nn.Embedding(2, 20)
        self.age_embed = nn.Embedding(36, 50)

        self.fc1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(70, 35),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(35, 2)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        # write the forward
```

In the above example, I assume age values will be integer `(25, 26, ..., 60)`, so for each possible value, we can learn a vector representation.

So, I propose to learn a `20d` representation of sex and `50d` representation of age. You can change the dimensions and do experiments to find an optimal value.